90s (?) movie about a children's book author with a lung disease
I'm searching for a film which I think was released in 90s. It is about a couple and the wife is an author of children's books who suffers from a terminal lung disease. The husband used to meet with another woman and the wife, believing he has affair with this woman, tells him just to wait until her death. But actually he had met with the woman to kill her so he can transfer her lungs to his wife and rescue her. In the final scene the man was waiting for his wife in a car while she was cheating on him with other man.

Sounds like "Lifebreath" also known as "Last Breath" from 1997

"When lovely New Yorker Chrystie Devoe (Francie Swift) is diagnosed with the life-threatening disease cystic fibrosis, her schoolteacher husband, Martin (Luke Perry), does everything in his power to procure a lung transplant for her. Chrystie's rare blood type limits the possibilities, so Martin resorts to extreme measures to ensure his spouse's survival with a plan that involves Gale Pullman (Gia Carides), a real estate agent who is a perfect donor candidate -- and unfortunately quite healthy."

In the film, he does cheat on his wife as an effort to find the "perfect donor."
As for the ending: "The end of the movie shows him outside waiting in a taxi cab while she is at some cheap motel having an affair on him, which earlier in the movie it showed her waiting in a taxi while he was having an affair"




This is it, Thank you "followthemeow"
